# No module named torch.distributed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pytorch

ImportError: No module named torch.distributed

```
File "train.py", line 4, in <module>
    import torch.distributed as dist
ImportError: No module named torch.distributed
```

I installed CUDA AND cuDNN then created env and installed pip3 install torch torchvision but getting error.

Comment: Did you remember to activate your virtual environment?

Comment: Yes I activated  virtual environment

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

1. Create a conda virtual environment:

   ```
   conda create -n env_pytorch python=3.6
   ```
2. Active this environment create above:

   ```
   source activate env_pytorch
   ```
3. Install PyTorch with pip or pip3:

   ```
   pip install torchvision --user
   ```